# How do I display the covariance matrix from proc glimmix or proc mixed?

Tags: sas, covariance-matrix

I am using proc glimmix and proc mixed to run a linear mixed model and am trying to look at the covariance matrix to see if it looks correct. How do I print it to the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `covb` option in the `model` statement.

```
proc glimmix data=sashelp.cars;
    model horsepower = msrp / covb;
run;
```